# Is there a clean way to instantiate a const std::string private member from a getenv call

Tags: c++, string, environment-variables

I have a class that needs to grab an environment variable and use it in various processing.  It should be const.  My understanding of constness is that it must be instantiated on initialization.  So something like this would work

```
class C 
{
public:
  C() : idFromEnv(getenv("ENV")) {}

private:
  std::string idFromEnv;

};
```

But that isn't a safe way of doing it because an exception will be thrown if the string is null.  I thought there might be a way of incorporating ternary operators to do this.
Something like this, but this is really ugly:

```
class C
{
  public:
  C() : idFromEnv(getenv("ENV") ? getenv("ENV") : "UNKNOWN") 
  {
      std::cout << idFromEnv << "\n";
  }

  private:
  const std::string idFromEnv;
};
```

I'm not using that.  Anyone have any more elegant suggestions?

---

Based on suggestions, I tried this.  It does work.  Not quite what I had in mind.

```
class C 
{
    public:
    
    inline const std::string getEnvString(const char *env) 
    {
        char* cStr = getenv(env);
        return(std::string(cStr ? cStr : "UNKNOWN"));
    }
    
    C() : idFromEnv(getEnvString("ENV"))
    {
        std::cout << idFromEnv << "\n";
    }
    
    private:
    const std::string idFromEnv;
};
```

Comment: I'd use a tightly scoped helper function to get the calls to `getenv` down to one.

Comment: std::string throws the exception in the constructor when you pass a null value

Comment: @mreff555 But you could have your own function, say, `std::string getVariableFromEnv()` which will call `getenv()` and return either the result or `"UNKNOWN"` string.

Comment: In what way is the approach you tried based on suggestions "not quite what you had in mind"?

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a default member initializer.

So instead of writing it in the constructor, you would add a default value for `idFromEnv`:

```cpp
class C
{
public:
    C() = default;
private:
    std::string idFromEnv = getenv("ENV") ? getenv("ENV") : "UNKNOWN";;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding of constness is that it must be instantiated on initialization.

There is no `const` issues in the 1st example you present, so there is no need to initialize `idFromEnv` in the constructor's initialization list if you don't want to. You *can* assign it in the constructor's body instead, eg:

```cpp
class C 
{
public:
  C()
  {
    char* cStr = getenv("ENV");
    idFromEnv = cStr ? cStr : "UNKNOWN";
  }

private:
  std::string idFromEnv;
};
```

But, if `idFromEnv` needs to be `const`, then yes, you have to initialize it in the constructor's initialization list instead.  So using a helper function to wrap the extra `getenv()` handling is really your best option, eg:

```cpp
std::string getenvstr(const char *env)
{
  char* cStr = getenv(env);
  return cStr ? cStr : "UNKNOWN";
}

class C 
{
public:
  C() : idFromEnv(getenvstr("ENV")) {}

private:
  const std::string idFromEnv;
};
```

Comment: Do you think there would be an advantage to inlining the function?  My concern is that if compiler optimization attempted to instantiate the string first?